# Parte condicional no funciona en Python

Tags: python

Estoy retomando esto de la programación después de unos 3 años de dejarla y tengo un problema en Python 3, todo va bien hasta que llega a la parte de if, cuando llega a esa parte, lo que hace es que independientemente de la opción que elija, me salta directamente al print que dice "Bienvenido sea", en pocas palabras, el if no esta funcionando para nada

```py
print("¿Cuál es su nombre? ") 

print ()

name = input ("Mi nombre es: ") 

print()

print ("Hola, ¿así que su nombre es", name, " ?")

print ()

print ("1. Sí")

print ("2. No")

confirmation = input ()

if confirmation == 1:

    print ("Bienvenido", name)
   

elif confirmation == 2:

     print ("Porfavor, introduzca su nombre de nuevo:")

     print ()

     name = int ()

     print ()

print ("Bienvenido sea", name)
```

Comment: Probaste con convertir el valor del input en int?

Comment: Te refieres a poner confirmation = int () en vez de confirmation = input ()? Si, lo intente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la variable confirmation que te la detecta como string, una de las soluciones es en el If añadir int(confirmation).

Quedaría así el codigo:

```
print("¿Cuál es su nombre? ") 

print ()

name = input ("Mi nombre es: ") 

print()

print ("Hola, ¿así que su nombre es", name, " ?")

print ()

print ("1. Sí")

print ("2. No")

confirmation = input ()

if int(confirmation) == 1:

    print ("Bienvenido", name)


elif int(confirmation) == 2:

    print ("Porfavor, introduzca su nombre de nuevo:")

    print ()

    name = input ()

    print ("Bienvenido sea", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema reside en que en que al declarar la variable "confirmation" no la declaras como un int, para que el condicional funcione, la declaración debería ser de esta manera ya que de tu forma, el programa no detecta la variable como un entero

```
confirmation = int(input())
```

De todas maneras, si quisieras declarar la variable como has hecho tu, la cabecera de los if debería de ser así

```
if confirmation == "1":
if confirmation == "2":
```

En el segundo if hay otro problema a la hora de volver a cambiar la variable name, donde la declaras como un int y en realidad es una cadena de caracteres, el código sería tal que así

```
elif confirmation == 2:

print("Porfavor, introduzca su nombre de nuevo:")
print()
name = input()

print()
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias crack, me sirvio, me estaba dando problemas ya que al cumplir la condicion 1 me estaba tirando los dos "Bienvenidos", pero lo arregle alineando el último print con los codigos de la condicion 2, no estoy acostumbrado a lenguajes que no usan puntuacion al final